# bash script to edit all files in a dir

Tags: linux, bash, loops, sed

trying to edit all log files from a chat dir to replace a string value found on the next line after a given value.

The code below works:

```
sed '/Did cool stuff/{n;s/how cool/sweet as bru/g} logname.log
```

But when attempting to exec `bash` it never completes, *i.e.* just hangs:

```
#!home/bin/bash
for file in /home/logs/*.log ; do
    sed '/Did cool stuff/{n;s/how cool/sweet as bru/g}' ;
done
```

Feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 5):

For the `for` loop you need the loop variable on the command line, if you leave the filename off `sed` will read from standard input, and the script will hang waiting for input.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /home/logs/*.log ; do
    sed '/Did cool stuff/{n;s/how cool/sweet as bru/g}' "$file";
done
```

But `for` is not needed, `sed` can do that already.

```
sed '/Did cool stuff/{n;s/how cool/sweet as bru/g}' /home/logs/*.log
```

If you want to alter the file content instead of display the altered version use `-i`.

```
sed -i '/Did cool stuff/{n;s/how cool/sweet as bru/g}' /home/logs/*.log
```

Comment: Thanks forgot the file name- obvious mistake

Comment: Working fine except in the case of a dupe line in the first & second string; EX LINE 4  'Did cool stuff' ; LINE5 'Did cool stuff' ; LINE6 'how cool'; line 6 does not substitute